# ¿Como mostrar en una table el nombre del usuario en sesión (logueado)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
<table class="table">
  @foreach($report->orders as $order)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $order->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $order->product_id }}</td>
      <td>Jesus</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

En el `td` 3 como puedo mostrar el `name` del usuario en sesión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Suponiendo que utilizas Auth `<td>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo así, a través del helper `auth`:

Asignando su valor a una variable para mandarlo a la vista desde el controlador:

```
$user = auth()->user();
```

O desde la vista así:

```
{{ auth()->user() }}
```

**Referencia**

- [`auth helper`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-auth)